# How to Change this to letters?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a Job No. : "02268-0000"

and if I pressed a button to it will look like this ---> "02268-ALL"
the button will call all job numbers having the same first set of numbers "02268"
and i want it to appear in the textbox of the job no. that i already call all the number having the same first set of numbers.

Thanks for your help... :)

Comment: This question cannot be answered the way it is currently written.  Please make some changes so we can help.

Comment: ok i will change it..

Comment: Also, it is tagged `sql` but there is no mention of databases or queries.

Comment: `MyString = MyString.Replace("0000", "ALL")`

Comment: Dim rep As String
            rep = txtfjobno.Text
            txtfjobno.Text = rep.Replace("0000", "ALL")

Comment: ... or: `Dim rep As String = txtfjobno.Text.Replace("0000", "ALL")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select replace('02268-0000','0000','ALL')
```